# How to align icons fontawesome and text inside button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am noob at css. Can someone show me how to properly align this text and icons from above and below? 
I don't know how to go about it...

I have example of my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">

<style>
button {
border-radius: 4px;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px 10px;
}

button::before {
display: block;
}
</style>

<button class="fas fa-undo" onclick="onUndo()" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 2px;">Undo</button>
<button class="fas fa-redo" onclick="onRedo()" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 2px;">Redo</button>
<button class="fas fa-table" id="btnCreateTable" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 2px;">Add table</button>
<button class="fas fa-edit" id="btnRenameTable" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 2px;">Rename table</button>
<button class="fas fa-trash-alt" id="btnDeleteTable" style="margin-left: 5px;margin-bottom: 2px;">Delete table</button>
<button class="fas fa-plus" id="btnAddRow" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 2px;">Add row</button>
<button class="fas fa-pen-square" id="btnEditRow" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 2px;">Edit row</button>
<button class="fas fa-minus" id="btnDeleteRow" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 2px;">Delete row</button>
<button class="fas fa-sitemap" id="btnInfo" style="margin-left: 5px;">Connection info</button>
```

but this looks really strange on that compiler. The real look is here:

[image]

As you can see this is not center of button. Can someone help?

Comment: Please add your button styles, cause so far you provided [this](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/5xsmudta/1/)... and I guess you want [that](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/5xsmudta/3/).

Comment: Ye, thanks. Well, but in my code that css code doesn't work. Text and icons inside button are still the same.

Comment: That's because you have other styles for buttons... you gotta use your browser Inspector (F12) and than examine what styles have been applied.

Comment: well really... something from hidden folder was changing my css. Thanks man!